# Office applications open files stored on local Samba server in protected view

Tags: samba, microsoft-office-2016

**The Environment**

I have two Samba servers that I use as file servers. The older one runs CentOS 7, the newer one runs Rocky Linux, and I'm working on retiring the older one. I'm opening the files in question in Office 2016 on Windows 10.

**The problem:**

Whenever I open any Office file that is stored on the newer of the two, Office always opens it in protected view on the basis that "this file originated from the internet." This does not affect the older system. Both systems are in the same workgroup and the same subnet. I've added the network drive name for the newer system to the trusted locations in the trust center, but it continues to give me this message.

**Desired state:**

I would like to have the server recognized as part of the local network so that I do not have to turn off protected mode each and every time I need to edit the documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by adding that fileserver to the local intranet zone in the security settings in internet settings in the Control Panel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below?
Adding the Samba server as a trusted locations should resolve the issue..

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-remove-or-change-a-trusted-location-in-microsoft-office-7ee1cdc2-483e-4cbb-bcb3-4e7c67147fb4

Comment: ```I've added the network drive name for the newer system to the trusted locations in the trust center, but it continues to give me this message.```